# MySQL: Extract Select in "Module"

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT pm.id 
FROM r2r.partmaster pm
WHERE pm.id NOT IN (SELECT pd.part_num FROM wpsapi4.product_details pd)
```

The there a way to modularize the statement, for instance, extract the second select statement in a file and call this file instead of writing the whole query?

Comment: An easy way would be to create a view from the second query. How does that sound like?

Comment: For example?...

Comment: The query seems pretty simple.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @g_bor how does that work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff its just an example. I want to exclude some specific users for multiple queries

Comment: It looks like this: create view partnums as select pd.part_num from wpsapi4.product_details pd) and then select pm.id from r2r.partmaster pm where pm.id not in (select * from partnums) This works well when the second query is complicated.

Comment: Thank you g_bor! This is exactly what i was searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to reuse SQL. Its possible via SQL-Functions and SQL-Procedures

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is performance, then use `NOT EXISTS` and be sure you have the correct index:

```
SELECT pm.id
FROM r2r.partmaster pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM wpsapi4.product_details pd
                  WHERE pm.id = pd.part_num
                 );
```

You want to be sure that you have an index on `wpsapi4.product_details(part_num)`.

I can think of no reason to break out such a simple subquery into another table.

Comment: I dont care about performance, i want the query to look cleaner and be able to reuse queries